# How can I customize the validation error message in the Symfony's Controller

Tags: php, ajax, validation, symfony

I have an ajax call to an url corresponding to a symfony2 coded page and in that page I have validation of one data passed to the page.

My validator :

```
/**
* @Assert\Regex(pattern="/^(https?:\/\/)/", message="wrong_string", groups={"searchnow_url_post"})
...
*/
public $searchstring;
```

When I build the answer to the ajax call I write it directly in the controller using `JsonResponse`. My problem is when validation produces an error I do something like:

```
return new JsonResponse(array(
    'status' => 401,
    'error_msg'=> (string)$errors   
));
```

To be more precise, the whole controller is :

```
class BaseController extends Controller
{
public function searchnow_url_postAction(){
    $input_string=$_REQUEST['src'];

    $search_string= new Searchstring();
    $search_string->setSearchstring($input_string);

    //qui devo usare il validation group "search_now"
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($search_string, null, array('searchnow_url_post'));
    if (count($errors) > 0){
        $status=401;
        return new JsonResponse(
            array('status' => 401,
                'error_msg'=> (string) $errors  
        ));
    }
    else
        return new JsonResponse(array('status' => 200));
    }
}
```

(The above validator is extracted from the entity Searchstring)

In the javascript I receive in `error_msg` :

> "Object(MemoBundle\Entity\Searchstring).searchstring: Wrong string."

but this is not good.

I would like to receive in `error_msg`  only the message "Wrong string" without "Object(MemoBundle\Entity\Searchstring).searchstring:".

How can I do to receive this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the solution. The issue was very simple but being new to Symfony2 I had some difficulties to focalize my problem.

I need to use the getMessage() method of ConstraintViolation object , where a list of this objects is returned from validate method of validator object.

To write some code lines the controller above now  sounds like this:

```
public function searchnow_url_postAction(){
    $input_string=$_REQUEST['src'];

    $search_string= new Searchstring();
    $search_string->setSearchstring($input_string);

    //qui devo usare il validation group "search_now"
    $validator = $this->get('validator');
    $errors = $validator->validate($search_string, null, array('searchnow_url_post'));
    if (count($errors) > 0){

        $error_ret_msg='';
        foreach ($errors as $error){
            $error_ret_msg.=$error->getMessage()."|";
        }

        $status=401;
        return new JsonResponse(
            array('status' => 401,
                'error_msg'=> $error_ret_msg,
        ));
    }
    else
        return new JsonResponse(array('status' => 200));
}
```

I've used a foreach cycle in the case there are more validation constraints violated for the same variable, separating each error message with a "|".

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown any of the code responsible for generating the output itself. As you can see, your error message showed up as expected

Somewhere you are calling your form object,

$form->getErrors( ... )

This is the relevant block.

Comment: as you can see I've added the whole controller code. My point is that I do not want the part of error message "Object(MemoBundle\Entity\Searchstring).searchstring:" but I want an error message totally customized. I am new to Symfony2 so I don't know if what I want is obtainable with the message parameter in the validator or in another way. Hope I've been more clear now.